# Best way to transfer data struct between two ASP.NET Core API's

Tags: c#, json, data-structures

I have two API's. API-1 generates a huge dataset, something like

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string<List<object>>> data_
```

My final goal is to find the most efficient way to transfer this data to API-2 deserialize it and return response to API-1.

I have found two approaches:

1. To generate JSON form the container and send the JSON to API-2. Here we have problem if the data is too big.
2. To save the JSON to a file and send the file API-2. Here we have a problem because the file usually gets like 400-500 mb in size.

So my question is, is there a way to transfer directly the data struct to API-2, without JSON serialization/deserialization.

Is there some way to send my **data_** container like bytes, and serialize it in API-2 ?

Comment: If you don' t know how to separate data in chunks, use USB drive instead. They are cheap now.

Comment: The data (whathever the size is) must travel between Api-1 and Api-2 so the only way to be sure of dont going above certain size is ... paginate the results and mark the response in API1 with some flag that says, 'ask me for more data from here'

Comment: What do you mean by API? is it REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described, it sounds that this approach of sending all the data in one API call is not suited here.

I suggest that you will send the data to API-2 in chunks.

In API-1 you will save the records with indication of [sent/not sent] in a database.
Then you should loop through the records, get chunks of them, and send the chunks to API-2.
When you get success from API-2, you should mark the records as "sent" in API1 DB.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer ! It will work nicely.